# Translating 5-wire camera output to composite signal

Tags: camera, video, video-transmitter

An existing OEM rearview camera has 5 wires (V+, LVDS+, LVDS-, LIN, ground). Is there a way to translate (hook up) this to a standard composite cable that goes into back of a aftermarket head unit?

All the cameras I have dealt with before had up to four cables (two for video in composite cable and up to two for power (or for a signal to turn power on for the camera)).

[Here](https://www.fullfatrr.com/gallery/albums/userpics/15719/Multiple%20cameras%7E0.pdf) is a wiring diagram and I am just looking to hook up a rearview camera (there is a total of 5 OEM cameras controlled by CAN-BUS but it's over my head and I want to bypass the entire module altogether, and hook up to a single camera directly).

[Here](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/87637/help-understanding-can-bus-signals-to-control-camera-module) is the original question that I am afraid is too complex and not worth tackling.

So, any help for hooking up the 5 wire set-up to a regular composite video input will be great.

Comment: Unlikely possible, unless you know what protocol the LVDS data is and how to receive it and retransmit as composite.

Answer (score 1):

LVDS stands for Low Voltage Differential Signaling. Contrary to composite, it is a fully digital video interface (as in HDMI and the likes).

The way this works is by driving the + and - signal in changing polarities to indicate 1's and 0's. A driver takes lots of parallel information (pixels) and sends this with very high speeds trough this LVDS interface. A decoder does the reverse of this on the other end. There are many benefits for sending data in this way, reduced cabling, reduced emissions etc. Wikipedia has a fine resource on this:
[image]
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-voltage_differential_signaling

This semiconductor manufacturer (Maxim) even makes chips that are just for this purpose, intended for automotive applications: https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/design/technical-documents/app-notes/4/4019.html

Unfortunately there is no way to hook up these interfaces together directly. LVDS is digital, the one you want is analog. It is possible to convert though, if you have the time and patience to develop something like this.

Edit:
As has been pointed out this is not actually the answer to your question. I feel like this is beyond the scope of what you are trying to do but in order to convert such a signal to composite consider:

- Converting the LVDS stream back to usable parallel information using some  kind of SerDes. The maxim chip I linked to is an example of a device that can decode such a signal, but you'll have to be very careful that the camera module and LVDS de-serializer use the exact same protocol/data formatting since LVDS does not specify the actual protocol, just the physical interface. I have experience with FPD-Link protocol (Texas instruments), but I honestly couldn't tell you for your camera module. If you opt for an FPGA based solution you have more freedom in this regard since you could just design the de-serialization yourself.
- Now you'd need to re-arrange this incoming data stream to some format that would work for the device that will be generating the analog composite signal. Video processing could happen here as well based on your preferences.
- The final step is feeding this new datastream to some kind of DAC device, capable of generating signals usable for composite video. Since this is a quite common occurance, off-the-shelf IC's exist to do this for you. Something like the ADV7120 could suit you https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/adv7120.pdf

There are multiple ways to go about this, FPGA's, microprocessors with LVDS/media interfaces or special purpose IC's could help you do all this

Comment: Although interesting, this does not explain how to convert the LVDS data stream into an analog, composite video signal (which was the question).

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking the time to provide feedback! You are absolutely right, I kind of looked over that fact. I included some information on the basic conversion steps. I hope this is of use to someone.

Comment: LVDS is an electrical protocol, not an video interface. Sure many devices send serialized digital video data with LVDS and thus can be received via SerDes as you say but it requires multiple pairs of LVDS wires including a clock, but the camera in question has only one LVDS pair so the protocol is unknown, it has no clock and can't be received by the method you give in your answer so it is not correct.

Comment: @Thijs - Hi, Please be careful not to have long discussions in comments, as that is not an [allowed use of comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work). The comments to you above giving "constructive criticism" are allowed, and your intended response would be either to change your answer to address them, or to briefly reply saying that you disagree and why - but not to write 6 long comments in reply. We (moderators) sometimes get complaints about this type of (ab)use of comments. I know it can be difficult, but please avoid using comments like a forum. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Sam, again thank you for pointing out ES etiquette. I will move my thoughts elsewhere.

Comment: @Thijs - You're welcome. I know the rules and etiquette on Stack Exchange are different to most other sites. FYI one more way to respond to comments that I forgot to mention, provided that your response is relevant to the answer, is to copy the other person's comment into your answer (prefixed with `>` so that it shows as quoted) and then follow it with your response - all within your answer. That keeps the long response out of comments :-) I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! it seems all of this is way above my level of expertise and the best option may be just to put in new cameras with analog interface. Thanks again for your time and explanation.